# RStudio compatibility with R version 4.2.0

Tags: r, rstudio

Is RStudio 2021.09.0+351 compatible with R version 4.2.0?
I am on Windows 8.1 with UCRT installed, using RStudio 2021.09.0+351. It works fine with R 4.1.3, but if I update to 4.2.0, then RStudio does not even start.
I get the following Startup Failure Report.

```
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2021.09.0+351, "Ghost Orchid" (077589bc, 2021-09-20) for Windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

### Error message

[No error available]

### Process Output

The R session exited with code -1073740791. 

Error output:


[No errors emitted]


Standard output:


[No output emitted]


### Logs

*C:/Users/FJG/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-FJG.log*


2022-05-19T13:56:53.053155Z [rsession-FJG] WARNING findProgramOnPath returns wrong result: C:\PROGRA~1\texlive\2019\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe != C:/Program Files/texlive/2019/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::FilePath __cdecl rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &) src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:1206
2022-05-19T13:57:02.575089Z [rsession-FJG] ERROR system error 10053 (Se ha anulado una conexi�n establecida por el software en su equipo host.) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) src/cpp/session/http/SessionWin32HttpConnectionListener.cpp:114; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) src/cpp/session/http/SessionWin32HttpConnectionListener.cpp:119
2022-05-19T13:57:02.575089Z [rsession-FJG] ERROR system error 10053 (Se ha anulado una conexi�n establecida por el software en su equipo host.) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) src/cpp/session/http/SessionWin32HttpConnectionListener.cpp:114; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) src/cpp/session/http/SessionWin32HttpConnectionListener.cpp:119
```

May I update to RStudio-2022.02.2-485 using Windows 8.1?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You always should update RStudio when you update R to a new major version. You have my permission to do so, fwiw. But you need a 64 bit OS. You should look into upgrading your OS anyway.

Comment: I have a 64bit OS Windows 8.1, but it is not clear to my If I can update to RStudio-2022.02.2-485, since in the download RStudio web says: Requires Windows 10/11 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that the problems you see are due to RStudio/R4.2 compatibility. It is more probably an OS compatibility issue - Windows 8.1 is quite old, and a lot can go wrong.

The first thing to note is the comment in the [download page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/):

> This build requires UCRT, which is part of Windows since Windows 10
> and Windows Server 2016. On older systems, UCRT has to be installed
> manually from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c).

If installing UCRT doesn't suffice, I'd suggest to carefully go over the doc section [Does R run under Windows Vista/7/8/10/11/Server](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.R-4.2.0.html#Does-R-run-under-Windows-Vista_003f) (although it is mostly about user permissions, you might catch something relevant to your case)

Comment: Thanls a lot for the advice! I eventually found that  RStudio-2022.02.2-485 works under Windows 8.1 and R 4.2.0. So the problem is solved at the moment, even if I have to think in updating my OS.